# javascript hamburger menu not working with node/ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, navbar

I am trying to use a hamburger menu for a nav bar and it isnt working.
I first had an issue where I was getting "GET /javascript/menu.js 404" in the terminal when loading the page. This lead me to believe that it couldnt find the files. I believe I was able to fix that issue by adding this to my server.js

`app.use("/javascript", express.static('javascript'))`

However when clicking on the hamburger it still does not bring up the nav links. im attempting to use an event listener to detect a click on the "toggle-btn" and the make the "navbar-links" be active. This should override

display: none;

with the later

display: flex;

but it doesnt and im now at a loss.

here is the html for the nav bar:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/nav.css">
<script src="/javascript/menu.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
   <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="title">
      <%= (typeof title !="undefined" ? title : "" ) %>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-btn">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </a>
    <div class="navbar-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/" class="nav-item">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-item" href="/meals/new">ADD Meals</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-item" href="/meals/index">ALL Meals</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

here is the css im using:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .toggle-btn {
    display: flex;
  }

  .navbar-links {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }

  .navbar-links ul {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .navbar-links li {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .navbar-links li a {
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
  }

  .navbar-links.active {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

and here is the javascript:

```
const toggleButton = document.querySelector('.toggle-btn')
const navbarLinks = document.querySelector('.navbar-links')

toggleButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

Iv tried changing the javascript from getElementByClass to querySelector but that didnt seem to help. Im also not convinced that adding the line in my server.js actually fixed the potential root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you put `console.log('test')` in your event listener, does it show up in the inspect tool when you click on the button ?

Also you didn't provide the code for the *active* css class, but maybe adding `display: flex !important;` could fix the issue

Comment: I tried putting a console log in the javascript event listener and it does not show.